# Use results of a sql query in another query

Tags: sql

I have the following query in SQL server 2008:

```
   select jra.xmin, jra.xmax, jra.ymin, jra.ymax, jra.zmin,
      jra.zmax
   from JRange jra
   join XCatalogDefinition xmf on xmf.OidOrigin = jra.Oid
   join JDPart jdp on jdp.Oid = xmf.OidDestination
   join JDObject jdo on jdo.Oid = jra.Oid
   join JNamedItem jni on jni.Oid = jdo.Oid
   where jni.itemname like 'volumen_example%'
```

The results are the following (it returns two rows)

```
xmin     xmax    ymin    ymax     zmin     zmax
1103.55 1104.91 1344.31 1346.46   637.66  639.28
1106.56 1107.91 1344.31 1346.46   637.66  639.28
```

Then I need to use above values in another query;

```
 select 
    jni.ItemName, jdp.PartNumber, wrp.Module
 from JRange jra
 join XmadeFrom xmf on xmf.OidOrigin = jra.Oid
 join JDPart jdp on jdp.Oid = xmf.OidDestination
 join WRPARTSATTRIBUTE wrp on wrp.Oid = jra.Oid
 join JDObject jdo on jdo.Oid = jra.Oid
 join JNamedItem jni on jni.Oid = jdo.Oid

 where jra.xmin > (value xmin of the above results)
    AND jra.xmax < (value xmax of the above results)
    and jra.ymin > (value ymin of the above results)
    and jra.ymax < (value ymax of the above results)
    and jra.zmin > (value zmin of the above results)
    and jra.zmax < (value zmax of the above results)
```

Please, could you help me to create a only query for get this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your first query returns two rows. In your query you have eg _jra.xmin>(value xmin of above results)_, do you mean bigger than any xmin in the above results?

Comment: No, I need to run the second query by each row of the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make another join with that subquery table and giving it alias `jra2`:

```
select jni.ItemName, jdp.PartNumber, wrp.Module
 from JRange jra
 join XmadeFrom xmf on xmf.OidOrigin = jra.Oid
 join JDPart jdp on jdp.Oid = xmf.OidDestination
 join WRPARTSATTRIBUTE wrp on wrp.Oid = jra.Oid
 join JDObject jdo on jdo.Oid = jra.Oid
 join JNamedItem jni on jni.Oid = jdo.Oid
 join 
 (select jra.Oid, jra.xmin, jra.xmax, jra.ymin, jra.ymax, jra.zmin,
      jra.zmax
   from JRange jra
   join XCatalogDefinition xmf on xmf.OidOrigin = jra.Oid
   join JDPart jdp on jdp.Oid = xmf.OidDestination
   join JDObject jdo on jdo.Oid = jra.Oid
   join JNamedItem jni on jni.Oid = jdo.Oid
   where jni.itemname like 'volumen_example%') jra2

 where jra.xmin > jra2.xmin
    AND jra.xmax < jra2.xmax
    and jra.ymin > jra2.ymin
    and jra.ymax < jra2.ymax
    and jra.zmin > jra2.zmin
    and jra.zmax < jra2.zmax
```

Comment: Hi Jay, Thank you for your reply. The return query is empty. Jra.oid is not equal to jra2.oid.

Comment: I need to run the second query by each row of the first query.